# Use of unassigned local variable `IsZoneEmpty'

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, unityscript

Why is it saying use of unassigned variable `isZoneEmpty`. I'm having a hard time finding out why. Because I am using the variable in the if statement.Please Help me. Why is it saying use of unassigned variable `isZoneEmpty`. I'm having a hard time finding out why. Because I am using the variable in the if statement.Please Help me.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SpawnZone : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Vector3 Zone1;
    private Vector3 Zone2;
    private Vector3 Zone3;
    private Vector3 Zone4;
    private Vector3 Zone5;

    public Vector3 Zone1L;
    public Vector3 Zone2L;
    public Vector3 Zone3L;
    public Vector3 Zone4L;
    public Vector3 Zone5L;

    public GameObject Monster;

    GameObject SpawnedM;

    void Start () 
    {
        Dictionary <Vector3,bool> IsZoneEmpty; new Dictionary <Vector3,bool>();

        {
            IsZoneEmpty.Add(Zone1,true);
            IsZoneEmpty.Add(Zone2,true);
            IsZoneEmpty.Add(Zone3,true);
            IsZoneEmpty.Add(Zone4,true);
            IsZoneEmpty.Add (Zone5,true);

            if (IsZoneEmpty[Zone1] == true) 
            {
                SpawnedM = Instantiate(Monster,Zone1L, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                Debug.Log("Monster Spawned In Zone 1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You declare a variable but don't initialize it. `Dictionary <Vector3,bool> IsZoneEmpty;` You need something like `Dictionary <Vector3,bool> IsZoneEmpty = new Dictionary <Vector3,bool>();`

Comment: I did it's in the code.

Comment: @DanSingh no, you didn't

Comment: @DanSingh No. see `;` between your stmts...

Comment: Oh yes i didn't even catch that thank you.

Comment: This is not UnityScript. It shouldn't be tagged as such.

Answer (score 1):

The first line in your `Start()` Method should be changed to this

```
Dictionary <Vector3,bool> IsZoneEmpty = new Dictionary <Vector3,bool>(); //(`;` to `=`)
```

you can make it smaller just by using [var](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

```
var IsZoneEmpty = new Dictionary <Vector3,bool>();
```

You should [initialize variables before using them in `C#`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Please explain the reason so I can improve the answer and make the community a better place.

Comment: In unity the start doesn't need to have ;.  And your right I didn't even catch that thanks.